# CMD Batch and 7z : Capture the progress of the extraction

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 7zip, findstr

I'm trying to extract something using the 7zip command line tool from a batch file
and i want just the percentage progress to appear

my code is

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3 delims=. " %%i in (
'7z x "file.rar" ^| findstr /b /r " [0-9][0-9]*\%%"'
) do (
cls
echo %%i
)
PAUSE
```

but all i get out is just blank during the whole extracting progress .

what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a FOR /F take the whole output of a command and when the command is finished it begins to iterate over the lines.
Well, this can't be used to solve your task.

But you can pipe the output to another process, in this sample I use the same batch as the second process ( `%~f0` is the batch itself )

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1"==":pipe" goto %~1

7z x "file.rar" | findstr /b /r " [0-9][0-9]*\%%" | "%~f0" :pipe
echo Ready
exit /b

:pipe
set "line="
set /p line=
if defined line (
    echo #### !line!
    goto :pipe
)
```